# Fitness tracker without tracking

Tags: passive-tracker

I'm looking for a fitness tracker which does not require uploading all my data to some server. It is ok if the device has this feature as long as I can just not use it.

I don't care what i did a month ago. However I would like to check my heartrate while running/hiking and show distance and elevation gain/loss if possible.

I would prefere a small/light one. After that, the more features are usable without syncing the better.